# Mule - do something when an ArrayList is empty

Tags: jdbc, arraylist, maps, mule, payload

I have a Mule flow which is looking up a value in a database and returning the results in maps format, as an ArrayList. I'm then logging the payload directly after making the DB call to check the response. An example of a good response is:

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [{ID=1234567, NAME=Test}]
```

I'd like to include a choice element in the next stage of my flow to handle responses where no records are found, which look like this:

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: []
```

Which expression would I use to direct the flow in this instance? I've tried `#[payload=='']`, `#[payload=='[]'` and `#[payload==null]` with no success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just discovered the answer to this. Checking the payload size like so:

```
<when expression="#[payload.size()==0]">
    ...
</when>
```

I would still be interested in hearing if there is a better/alternative way of doing this...

Comment: I tried the same, but i am getting exception  Execution of the expression " #[message.payload.size() == 0]" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: LinkedList  ? how should i solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

`#[payload == empty]` checks for empty payload

Answer (score 0):

Convert object to xml and filter with `#[payload != '<linked-list/>']`